# How to fetch only required objects by using FetchType.EAGER in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public @Data class User 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private long userId;
    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="MIDDLENAME")
    private String middleName;
    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;

    //@JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Dependent> dependents;

   //@JsonIgnore
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Claim> claims;

}
```

This is my User class. I want to fetch only dependents when querying for User at some point. I tried to use FetchType.EAGER. It worked fine. But at the same time it is fetching claims also. If I use lazy loading, it is giving "Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" exception.
I also tried @JsonIgnore, but its not solution for my problem. Please help to solve this.

Comment: I believe list are by default loaded lazily. using eager fetch on dependents only should have given you the expected result. How did you verify that claims were loaded too ? if you access `claims` inside the session, even if it was loaded lazily, it will load at that instant.

Comment: Can you show the Dependent entity ?

Comment: I think that you have problem with transaction. Do you pass your entity to another class and then try to get your collection?